# Error on JMS Queue because of destination in websphere used by Message Driven Beans

Tags: jms, ejb-3.0, message-queue, websphere-7, message-driven-bean

I am getting the following error:

Application EBS_Calc#EBS_Calc_EJB.jar#MBIntegrations has an , useJNDI, for which there is no corresponding property on the ActivationSpec class jms/ASQueue(com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jmsra.impl.JmsJcaActivationSpecImpl) of ResourceAdapter cells/USWSA0102235Node01Cell/nodes/USWSA0102235Node01/servers/server1/resources.xml#J2CResourceAdapter_1364909976437. This property will be ignored. This may have undesirable effects.

ActivationSpe W   J2CA0161W: The type of the object referred to by the supplied destination JNDI name is wrong. The object must implement javax.jms.destination. The destination JNDI name was: jms/ASQueue. The supplied objects class was: {1}

ActivationSpe E   J2CA0137E: The ActivationSpec validate() method failed with an InvalidPropertyException. The ActivationSpec is jms/ASQueue (com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jmsra.impl.JmsJcaActivationSpecImpl), which belongs to the installed ResourceAdapter cells/USWSA0102235Node01Cell/nodes/USWSA0102235Node01/servers/server1/resources.xml#J2CResourceAdapter_1364909976437 and is associated with the MDB application EBS_Calc#EBS_Calc_EJB.jar#MBIntegrations. See the following list of failed properties along with their values:

```
destination  null
destination  null
```

...

CWSJR1181E: The JMS activation specification has invalid values - the reason(s) for failing to validate the JMS activation specification are: [CWSJR1188E: The destination on a JMS activation specification must be given a value, CWSJR1192E: JMS activation specs using a destination type of queue must have a destination of type [com.ibm.websphere.sib.api.jms.JmsQueue] but the destination passed was of type [null]]

I have configured accordingly the queue and bus and destination in websphere

My java code looks as follows:

```
    @MessageDriven(mappedName = "jms/ASQueue", activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "connectionFactoryJndiName", propertyValue = "jms/CalcConnectionFactory"),         
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationName", propertyValue = "jms/calcInQueue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue")        })

    @Resources ({
      @Resource(name="jms/CalcConnectionFactory",        
                mappedName="jms/CalcConnectionFactory",   // External JNDI name 
                type=javax.jms.ConnectionFactory.class)
     })


    public class MBIntegrations implements MessageListener {

    private static final String CONNECTION_FACTORY_NAME = "jms/CalcConnectionFactory";
    private static final String DESTINATION_NAME = "jms/calcInQueue";

    @Resource
    private MessageDrivenContext mdc;

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MBIntegrations.class);

    public void onMessage(Message inMessage) {

        TextMessage msg = null;

        try {
            if (inMessage instanceof TextMessage) {
                msg = (TextMessage) inMessage;
                logger.info("MESSAGE BEAN: Message received: " + msg.getText());
            } else {
                logger.warn("Message of wrong type: "
                        + inMessage.getClass().getName());
            }

        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            mdc.setRollbackOnly();
        } catch (Throwable te) {
            te.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

and IBM binder

```
<message-driven name="MBIntegrations">
        <jca-adapter activation-spec-binding-name="jms/ASQueue"
        destination-binding-name="jms/ASQueue" />
        <resource-ref name="jms/CalcConnectionFactory"
        binding-name="jms/CalcConnectionFactory" />
        <resource-ref name="jdbc/OracleDS" binding-name="jdbc/ORACLE" />
    </message-driven>
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, could someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem in the binder after reviewing:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.ejbfep.multiplatform.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Fcejb_bindingsejbfp.html

there it said:

```
<jca-adapter activation-spec-binding-name=
 "jms/InternalProviderSpec" 
 destination-binding-name="jms/ServiceQueue"/>
```

so in my case would have been:

```
 ... destination-binding-name="jms/calcInQueue" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to WebSphere Admin console

Activation specifications - Open your Activation Specification

Destination JNDI name - may be wrong. If it is topic make sure you gave topic jndi name.